# Relationship between attributes inside the same entity and queries/view

Tags: sql, postgresql, relationship, entity-relationship

We have a entity `users` with attributes `id`, `name`. How to 'implement' the relationship between these users with rules:

- user can have a relationship ex. `lover`, `married`, `engaged` with
  another user
- there should be no duplicates (`Jack Anne`, `Anne Jack`)
- user can't have a relationship with himself
- any other that you find logical

`this is solely made up, just me learning db`

So I made this ER diagram, the blue lines is what I set to unique/alternate-key

[image]

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fQnefAs3i7pbN8NnzF5frW/2)

1. Is this the right approach or did I put it all together wrong?
2. How to solve this reverse uniqueness? In case you missed it, I could place 
   Jack-Anne to lovers, and Anne-Jack to married, even Jack-Jack (with ids). I 
   could use CHECK constraints to not be equal or one to have smaller id (which 
   wouldn't work with uuid). But is there a better way? Is the answer to this, 
   to do the whole logic at front-end at insert?
3. For the view, I get the right results but could that be done
   'better'? I just want to show the `users_relationship` with
   `users.name`, `rel_type.type`.

Thanks, any tips/suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it's a good approach, and is at least 3NF.
2. To avoid *symmetric duplicates*, add an extra constraint in the table `users_relationship`, as in:

   ```
   create table users_relationship (
     column1 definition,
     column2 definition,
     ...
     contraint uq_pair check (users_id < users_2_id)
     ...
   );
   ```
3. Yes, it looks fine.

Comment: how is that check gonna work if we have uuid... (and not serial)

Comment: Before inserting/updating, you sort the ids to make sure the lowest is in `users_id` and the highest in `users_2_id` .